# Building object from JSON data?

Tags: c#, json, class, object, asynchronous

So I have a City class I want to build when I get JSON data from a server.

```
public class City
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string mainCity { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public bool wasThereAnError { get; set; }

    public class CityResponse
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public List<City> result { get; set; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "\n\nID: \t\t" + id + "\nCountry: \t" + country + "\nRegion: \t\t" + region + "\nCity: \t\t" + mainCity + "\nLatitude: \t" + latitude + "\nLongitude: \t" + longitude + "\nComment: \t" + comment;
    }
}
```

Thats the class there.
So when I query for example:

```
    {"status":"okay","result":{"id":1,"country":"US","region":"NY","city":"Valhalla","latitude":41.0877,"longitude":-73.7768,"comment":"890068 monkeys"}}
```

I want the City class to get populated with the corresponding data.
Here is the web retrieval class I have that gets the data.

```
        async private Task<City> GetCityInformation(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));

        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //var cityRootaaa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City.CityResponse>(result);


        var cityRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City>(result);
        return cityRoot;
    }
}
```

However, when I debug, I can see that nothing is getting saved.
Originally, I had another status field above id in City, and when I debugged, "okay" was getting set in the status field however no other data was.
I'm not sure what to do with this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your json string contains object that has two properties, status and a city object so your type to deserialize a string like that should be:

```
public class CityResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public City result { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize it like this

```
var cityResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CityResponse>(result);
return cityResponse.City;
```

Or if you don't want to introduce new type you can use anonymous object as well

```
var cityResponseType = new { status = string.Empty, result = new City() };
var cityResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result, cityResponseType);
return cityResponse.result;
```